# Partial group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

QUERY:

```
select ws_path from workpaths where 
(
   (ws_path like '%R_%') or
   (ws_path like '%PB_%' ) or
   (ws_path like '%ST_%')
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
/x/eng/users/ST_3609843_ijti4689_3609843_1601272247
/x/eng/users/ST_3610020_zozt5229_3610020_1601282033
/x/eng/users/ST_3611181_zozt5229_3611181_1601282032
/x/eng/users/ST_3611226_zozt5229_3611226_1601282033
/x/eng/users-random/john/N_3582168_3551186_1601040805
/x/eng/users-random/james/N_3582619_3551186_1601041405
/x/eng/users-random/jimmy/N_3582791_3551186_1601042005
/x/eng/users/R_3606462_3606462_1601251334
/x/eng/users/R_3611775_3612090_1601290909
/x/eng/users/R_3612813_3613016_1601292252
```

Is there way to group partially by ST_, N_ and R_?
i.e. `group by ws_path` wont work at the moment for the obvious reason

I need to only look at the last item in the path (split by '/') and then the front part of splitting with '_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` to get the patterns being searched for and then `group by` the number of such occurrences.

```
select regexp_substr(ws_path,'\/R_|\/PB_|\/ST_'), count(*) 
from workpaths 
group by regexp_substr(ws_path,'\/R_|\/PB_|\/ST_')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is a good solution but can be expensive.  A simpler substring might be cheaper and faster:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (field1 VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl
        ( field1 )
VALUES  
('/x/eng/users/ST_3609843_ijti4689_3609843_1601272247'),
('/x/eng/users/ST_3610020_zozt5229_3610020_1601282033'),
('/x/eng/users/ST_3611181_zozt5229_3611181_1601282032'),
('/x/eng/users/ST_3611226_zozt5229_3611226_1601282033'),
('/x/eng/users-random/john/N_3582168_3551186_1601040805'),
('/x/eng/users-random/james/N_3582619_3551186_1601041405'),
('/x/eng/users-random/jimmy/N_3582791_3551186_1601042005'),
('/x/eng/users/R_3606462_3606462_1601251334'),
('/x/eng/users/R_3611775_3612090_1601290909'),
('/x/eng/users/R_3612813_3613016_1601292252');

SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%/ST_%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'st_count',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%/N_%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'n_count',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%/R_%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'r_count'
FROM dbo.tbl
```

Comment: it says ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: oh it looks like it's working if you remove ' from as